# ajuda htaccess e base url php

Tags: php, htaccess

estou tentando fazer url amigaveis com a classe baseurl e também com htaccess, mas algumas paginas como servicos e portfolio, estão bugadas, quando clico para ver o codigo aparece no caminho dos arquivos uma parte do nome da pagina , como exemplos

locahost/admin/port../assets........

locahost/admin/s./assets........

Já excluir o arquivo e refiz, mas continua a mesma coisa, comparei com as outras paginas e ta a mesma coisa, segue o codigo do htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewiteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1
```

Poderiam me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Por favor tente isso:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Tive um problema muito parecido e após muito tempo de pesquisa e com a ajuda de alguns documentos referentes ao ache cheguei ao código acima.

Comment: Poderia explicar o que o teu código difere do código da autora da pergunta? A única coisa que vejo que difere é um `[OR]` pra links simbólicos e você tirou o `MultiViews`, poderia explica como isto resolve o problema? Recomendo que leia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Por favor, antes de registrar uma critica favor ler a documentação do Apache.

Comment: Eu já li e entendo a documentação, o problema é fornecer um resposta dentro do *padrão de qualidade da comunidade* como o link indica: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer - não é uma critica negativa e sim construtiva. O problema aqui nada tem haver com a documentação mas sim que você não explicou como o código funciona, o que é relevante a resposta.